# Opensearch "[terms] query does not support [pname]"

Tags: opensearch

I'm trying to run this Opensearch query in devtools and am getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[terms] query does not support [pname]",
        "line": 16,
        "col": 33
      }
    ],
    "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
    "reason": "[12:33] [bool] failed to parse field [filter]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "parsing_exception",
      "reason": "[terms] query does not support [pname]",
      "line": 16,
      "col": 33
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I'm trying to get the number of documents for a pname 'John Smith' between two timestamps. I'm not quite sure why it's failing.

```
GET /persons*/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                            "gte": "2024-03-17",
                            "lte": "2024-03-19"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "pname": "John-Smith"
                  }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "pname_count": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "pname.keyword",
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I add `[ ]` around the term `[ "John-Smith" ]` like the docs say I then get the following error:

```
"reason": "failed to parse date field [2024-03-17] with format [epoch_millis]: [failed to parse date field [2024-03-17] with format [epoch_millis]]"
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [terms query](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/query-dsl/term/terms/) you should add `[]` like you mentioned. For range query you should add [format](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/query-dsl/term/range/#format) if the indexed data field format is not same with the query field format. In your cause @timestamp field is indexed with `epoch_millis` format but you send query with `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

#### Here is the accurate query:

```
GET /persons*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "2024-03-17",
              "lte": "2024-03-19",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "pname": ["John-Smith"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "pname_count": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "pname.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```